# Question about Crowdsale contract token cost

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, ether, crowdsale

I have a quick question. What line of code do i need to add or remove here

```
function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        token addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }
```

To make the Ether cost of each token where 1 ether gives you 2,500 token?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code,

```
uint etherCostOfEachToken
```

seems to be the price you are passing for each token in ether. For 1 ether to give 2500 token,your price needs to be

```
1 ether/2500 = 0.0004 ether for each token
```

Since solidity cannot handle decimal values right now, you need to set `price` as `0.0004*10^18 or 4e14`(you can use scientific notation in since solidity version [0.4.10](http://0.0004))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;` 

try `price = etherCostOfEachToken * 400 szabo;`
and give 1 as input for "ether cost for each token" parameter in interface.

By the way, I used `https://converter.murkin.me/` for ether conversions.